# Speed up MySQL query by skipping rows?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, gravityforms

I have a MySQL query to pull daily results from gravity forms submissions. However the table is now over 1,000,000 rows and the queries are taking a long time. I need to retain the historical data but is there a way to speed up the below query to skip until row 1000000 from the start?

I am a bit of hack with SQL queries, so any other tips to speed this up is appreciated!.. Much thanks

```
"SELECT code,Employee_Codes.entry_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}gf_entry E, 
(SELECT form_id, entry_id, meta_value AS code FROM {$wpdb->prefix}gf_entry_meta WHERE meta_key='70') 
Employee_Codes,
(SELECT form_id, entry_id, meta_value AS company_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}gf_entry_meta WHERE meta_key='71')
Company_IDs WHERE E.id=Employee_Codes.entry_id AND Company_IDs.entry_id=E.id AND
Company_IDs.company_id='{$company_id}' AND
E.date_created >='" . date("Y-m-d 00:00:00") . "' AND
E.date_created <= '" . date('Y-m-d 23:59:59') . "' AND Employee_Codes.form_id={$form_id}"
```

Comment: You can reduce the `date_created` by changing those two parts to just `DATE(E.date_created) = CURDATE()`. Otherwise, you can speed it up by making sure you have the correct indexes on the necessary columns

Comment: 1) Show source tables DDLs. 2) *skip until row 1000000 from the start?* What is "start"? while what ordering, by what table? 3) Move `AND Company_IDs.company_id='{$company_id}'` into  `Company_IDs` subquery.

Comment: Thank you both, again, I'm not too proficient with writing queries. the gf_entry_meta table is the one I'd like to skip on until row id 1000000 before the call is made.. Does that make sense?

Comment: See https://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/